# Implement terminal command recall

Tags: python, terminal, system-calls

In the command line when up and down arrow is pressed it shows the last command in the same line. I want to implement that functionality in my program. What I have done is store previous command in a list. I can iterate it from the end and print it out but I can only print out in a new line. What is that functionality called and how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It's called "history". It is implemented in [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html), and is automatically enabled for `input()` and `raw_input()` when the module is imported; only loading and saving the history needs to be handled by the implementor.